# Why $E_t(\epsilon_{t+1}) =0$, where $e_t$ is white noise process?

Tags: time-series

This should be a rather simple mathematical question.

Let $\{\epsilon_t\}$ be a white noise process, that is

- $E(\epsilon_t)=0$
- $E(\epsilon_t^2)=\sigma^2$
- $E(\epsilon_t \epsilon_s)=0$ for $t \neq s$

I just don't see why  $E_t(\epsilon_{t+1}) := E(\epsilon_{t+1}|\epsilon_t,\epsilon_{t-1},\ldots)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't see it because it does not hold in general.**

For

$$E(\epsilon_{t+1}|\epsilon_t,\epsilon_{t-1},\ldots)=0$$

to hold **we need the additional assumption of joint independence**, or at least of "mean-independence" (i.e. allowing for dependence expressed in higher moments). The term "white noise process" stops at the property of zero correlation, it does not impose independence.

Of course ever so often the two are assumed together, and conflating the two may slowly settle in.

Comment: Thank you @Alecos. 1. Is the joint independence you mentioned same as strict stationary? 2. I asked this because in the page 33 of [this file](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/papers/time_series_book.pdf), for MA process $x_t$, $E_t(x_{t+k})=\theta_k\epsilon_t+\theta_{k+1}\epsilon_{t-1}+\ldots$. So this should not hold for MA process without further assumption, right?

Comment: Independence and strict stationarity is totaly unrelated, look them up. For the MA process, obviously $E_t(x_{t+k})=\theta_k\epsilon_t+\theta_{k+1}\epsilon_{t-1}+\ldots$ is not zero since the actually realized $\epsilon$s will be non-zero in general - and the link does not say otherwise.

Comment: I'm not saying that $E_t(x_{t+k})$ shoud be 0. I mean the derivation of above equality requires the equation in my question. But I just found the answer. In page 10 it is assumed the discussion is restricted to $\epsilon_t$ iid normal.

Comment: Good to hear. As you can see, the "i.i.d." assumption is never far away...